# Hamiltonian $S^1$ actions with isolated fixed points

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry, torus-action, toric-varieties, open-problems

I have in mind the following question for some time. Is there an example of a compact symplectic manifold with a Hamiltonian $S^1$-action with isolated fixed points, that does not admit a compatible $S^1$-invariant Kahler strucutre? One would say, of course there should be such an example. But I have not seen any...

**Added,** 2009. Apparently this is an open problem.

**PS,** 2019. Not anymore!

Comment: wiki'd, per policy for known open problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nick Lindsay and have  just proved that such a manifold indeed exists. And surprise, surprise, this is Tolman's manifold. See Theorem 1.3 and Corollary 1.4 of our paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.02785

Answer (score 4):

Lerman has constructed such an example see http://arxiv.org/abs/dg-ga/9601012v1 , well it has an isolated fixed point but also some fixed connected submanifolds, so maybe not exactly what you want.

The construction has been later revisited by Kim http://www.mathjournals.org/mrl/2002-009-004/2002-009-004-002.pdf

(note to editors: I guess the creation of 'torus-action' tag migh be useful.)

Comment: Isn't it `toric-action`?

Comment: Actually, may be `circle-action` or `localization`?

Comment: It's definitely 'torus-action', see e.g. this famous book by Audin
http://books.google.fr/books?id=uKXO9BDsk_kC

That said we might also need 'toric-variety' or 'toric-geometry' at some point, but that's something else.

Comment: Thanks a lot for both refferences! But still I want an action such that all fixed points are isolated. Though indeed it is nice to know that there are non-Kahler examples with at least one isolated point. 

Answer (score 1):

Sue Tolman has shown that there are non-Kahler 6-dimensional manifolds admitting Hamiltonian 2-torus actions all of whose fixed points are isolated ( http://arxiv.org/abs/dg-ga/9511007 ) . This might be a good first place to look to see if one of the components of the action satisfy the criteria you want.

Interestingly, Karshon has shown ( in dg-ga/9510004 [sorry, I can only post one link as a new user]) that if a 4-manifold admits a Hamiltonian circle action, it must be Kahler.

Comment: Surprising and interesting! Perhaps the next thing to do is do a literature search for papers that cite Tolman's paper. 